# An exception of using dozer to copy data from map to java bean

Tags: dozer

I want to copy data from map(request.getParameterMap()) to java bean. For example:

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("payment_code", "1420956468542a2");
//...


public class PaymentLogDTO {
    @Mapping("payment_code")
    private String paymentCode;
    //...
}
```

but when I execute map method in unit test,

```
DozerBeanMapper dozer = new DozerBeanMapper();
dozer.map(map, PaymentLogDTO.class);
```

it failed. The exception message is:

```
org.dozer.MappingException: No such field found java.util.HashMap.payment_code
at org.dozer.util.ReflectionUtils.getFieldFromBean(ReflectionUtils.java:322)
at org.dozer.util.ReflectionUtils.getFieldFromBean(ReflectionUtils.java:320)
at org.dozer.util.ReflectionUtils.getFieldFromBean(ReflectionUtils.java:320)
at org.dozer.util.ReflectionUtils.getFieldFromBean(ReflectionUtils.java:309)
at org.dozer.propertydescriptor.FieldPropertyDescriptor$ChainedPropertyDescriptor.<init>(FieldPropertyDescriptor.java:104)
at org.dozer.propertydescriptor.FieldPropertyDescriptor.<init>(FieldPropertyDescriptor.java:51)
at org.dozer.propertydescriptor.PropertyDescriptorFactory.getPropertyDescriptor(PropertyDescriptorFactory.java:64)
at org.dozer.fieldmap.FieldMap.getSrcPropertyDescriptor(FieldMap.java:385)
at org.dozer.fieldmap.FieldMap.getSrcFieldValue(FieldMap.java:86)
at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapField(MappingProcessor.java:294)
at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:267)
at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapToDestObject(MappingProcessor.java:216)
at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.createByCreationDirectiveAndMap(MappingProcessor.java:196)
at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapGeneral(MappingProcessor.java:170)
at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:104)
at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:99)
at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.map(DozerBeanMapper.java:120)
at org.springside.modules.mapper.BeanMapper.map(BeanMapper.java:36)
```

Is there any method can solve this problem? That is I don't need to create a java bean using the same name of query paramter name as it's properties' names.

Answer (score 0):

The [@Mapping annotation](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/annotations.html) tells the source/destination **field**, it has nothing related to the Map class...

So with @Mapping("payment_code"), it looks for a **field** "payement_code", and not for an element in your map collection.